# match evaluation of multiple multi-valued attributes

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, xacml3, alfa

The XACML 3.0 specs state that for `<Match>` evaluation "the MatchId
function SHALL be applied between the `<AttributeValue>` and each
element of the bag returned from the `<AttributeDesignator>` or
`<AttributeSelector>` element." [7.6 Match evaluation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc489959586)

In the case that, for example, the attribute access-subject / 
subject-id returns a bag with more than one value, one should iterate
over these members until the matching function returns true. This is
clear and obvious.  Now in case the `<AllOf>` element has two `<Match>`es as
in conformance test `IIA007Policy.xml` (see below). It has a `Match` on
access-subject / subject-id being equal to "Julius Hibbert" and
access-subject / some-attribute being equal to "riddle me this".

Now assume that in a request, there are two attributes having  multiple members, how should the match be evaluated now?  Attribute1 has bag [1, 2, 3] and attribute2 has bag [a, b]. One can
start processing the members from the first attribute until a true is
returned and than continue with processing the next attribute etc, but
that would not cover all possible outcomes. Or, should the matching
functions be simultaneously applied to all combinations of the members
from the two bags `[{1,a},{1,b},{2,a},{2,b},{3,a},{3,b}]`? With large bags and/or many attributes, this will lead to a large set of combinations to process!

The specs, as far as I know, give no clue how the situation is handled
in case two or more attributes return bags with multiple members
within the same `<AllOf>` element. My questions are:

- did I miss something in the specs,
- is my interpretation correct?
- how is this handled in real implementations?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" PolicyId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:conformance-test:IIA007:policy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy:schema:os         access_control-xacml-2.0-policy-schema-os.xsd">
    <Description>
        Policy for Conformance Test IIA007.
    </Description>
    <Target/>
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:conformance-test:IIA007:rule">
        <Description>
            Julius Hibbert can read or write Bart Simpson's medical record.
        </Description>
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Julius Hibbert</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Match>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">riddle me this</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:conformance-test:some-attribute" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:anyURI-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">http://medico.com/record/patient/BartSimpson</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>
    </Rule>
</Policy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a policy that states (using ALFA notation):

```
 policy example{
     target clause role == "manager" and department == "sales"
     apply firstApplicable
     rule allow{
         permit
     }
 }
```

If the request you send contains 2 values for role ("manager" and "employee") and 3 values for department ("sales", "engineering", "finance"), then the response will be Permit. In plain old English, your question would be "Can the user who happens to be a manager and an employee and who belongs to the sales, engineering, and finance departments do X?"

The way the policy will be evaluated is that each match will be handled one after the other, independently:

1. Is there at least one value equal to manager? Yes there is. The first match is true.
2. Is there at least one value equal to sales? Yes there is. The second match is true.

It does not matter that there is an AllOf (or an AnyOf). Each match is first handled independently. The spec is quite clear on that.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Match does not apply to all combinations from the two attribute bags, because they have different `AttributeId`s. A `Match` applies only to the one `AttributeId` (and Category and Datatype and optional Issuer) specified in the `AttributeDesignator`. If the AttributeDesignator in the Match has AttributeId='attribute1', it only applies to attribute 'attribute1', it does not care about the others. Then, a Match always evaluates to True (if and only if any of the attribute value matched), or False, or Indeterminate.

Then, what the `AllOf` combines is just the Trues/Falses/Indeterminates returned by the `Match`es. The combination algorithm is defined in section 7.7 (Target evaluation) of the XACML spec. In the tables, it says "Match" for True, and "No Match" for False (don't ask me why they didn't just say True or False, I am not one of the authors). So for example, if all Matches return True, then AllOf returns True. But if at least one Match returns False, then AllOf returns False. (And you have the special case for Indeterminate.) So you may understand that the combination is actually more basic than what you had in mind, I guess.

Comment: I know that a Match applies to one AttributeId only. The issue is that in a single request for example the attribute 'access-subject.subject-id' can return several values [2.6 Multi-valued attributes](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc489959483) ("Alice", "Bob" and "Charlie") and 'resource.resource-id' another bunch of resources ("File1", "File2" and "File3").  Now if the AllOf element contains Matches on 'access-subject.subject-id' and 'resource.resource-id', How are these values iterated over comparing to the policy's value?

Comment: They are processed independently.

Comment: No matter whether they are multi-valued or not, since you evaluate each Match separately, as David said. And you evaluate **ALL** Matches **BEFORE** you evaluate the AllOf that contains them. So in your example, let's say the Match on subject-id returns True (i.e. 'File1' or 'File2' or 'File3' is equal to the AttributeValue in the policy assuming the MatchId is the string-equal function). And the Match on resource-id returns False (i.e. neither 'Alice' nor 'Bob' nor 'Charlie' matches the AttributeValue in the policy). Then (if there's no other Match in the AllOf) the AllOf returns False.

Comment: If this is still unclear, you can give us an actual example of AllOf in XACML that makes sense for your example of request attributes, and we can be more specific.